# Mule Dataweave Repeating XML Elements to Individually Named XML Elements

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

**Input XML**

```
<Address>
    <Street>Street Line 1</Street>
    <Street>Street Line 2</Street>
    <Street>Street Line 3</Street>
    <City>City</City>
    <Postcode>0000</Postcode>
</Address>
```

**Output XML Required**

```
<DeliveryAddress>
    <DA1>Street Line 1</DA1>
    <DA2>Street Line 2</DA2>
    <DA3>Street Line 3</DA3>
    <City>City</City>
    <Postcode>0000</Postcode>
</DeliveryAddress>
```

How can I use Dataweave to put each street element to a particular DA element in the outbound XML?

I've tried to use a *wildcard (Address.*Street) however this then puts the Street elements as a child element:

```
<DeliveryAddress>
    <DA1>
        <Street>Street 1</Street>
        <Street>Street 2</Street>
        <Street>Street 3</Street>
    </DA1>
    <City>City</City>
    <Postcode>0000</Postcode>
</DeliveryAddress>
```

Please help ^_^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The * wildcard is used to reference repeated elements, especially in XML format. Start from this point we can sequentially solve this problem:

1. Start from this expression `payload.Address.*Street` we will get a list of Street.
2. However, an error will occur if we directly use it in current DataWeave expression. Therefore wrap that expression inside a bracket: `(payload.Address.*Street)` to make it as an object instead of an array.
3. Now we just need to rename the *Street* tag to the correspond *DA(n)*. Hence we can utilize **map** operator to iterate each record, and use **brackets** or **quote marks**, `() or '' or ""` to enclose the keys of the output:

`("DA" ++ $$ + 1)` or `"DA$($$ + 1)"` are both equally returning the same result: DA1, DA2, DA3, ...

Therefore, the complete expression for this field should be: `(payload.Address.*Street map { ("DA" ++ $$ + 1): $ })`

Comment: Thanks for explaining this so well, it's worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Based on Suthony input i just replicated below you can find the dwl script

```
%dw 1.0
```

### %output application/xml

DeliveryAddress:{

```
(payload.Address.*Street map { 
    ("DA" ++ $$ + 1): $
}),
    city:payload.Address.City,
    PostCode:payload.Address.Postcode
```

}

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    DeliveryAddress: {
        (payload.Address.*Street map {
            ("DA" ++ $$ +1): $
        }),
        City: payload.Address.City,
        Postcode: payload.Address.Postcode
    }
}
```

1. Use map to iterate over Street element
2. `("DA" ++ $$+1)` to print DA1, DA2 and so on.